# File Picker Component - React

Tags: react.js, jsx

Created FilePickerComponent recently. I'm new to React/Web development. Could you please help reviewing this code -

```
export const FilePickerButton: React.FunctionComponent<FilePickerButtonFCProps> = ({
    position,
    ariaLabel,
    ariaDescription,
    disabled,
    iconName,
    toolbarButtonId,
    acceptParams,
    onClickEvent,
    ...props
}) => {
    const uploadRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const fileUploadRefLink: (e: FluentButtonEventType) => void = React.useCallback(
        (e) => {
            uploadRef.current?.click();

            const currentTarget = e.currentTarget as HTMLElement;
            (currentTarget.closest('.ms-Button') as HTMLElement)?.blur();
        },
        [uploadRef]
    );

    const onClick = React.useCallback((e) => {
        // uploading same file again works with clearing up cache
        e.target.value = '';
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <input
                type="file"
                ref={uploadRef}
                id={`${toolbarButtonId}`}
                accept={acceptParams}
                onChange={onClickEvent}
                onClick={onClick}
                className="fileUploadPicker"
            />
            <ToolbarButton
                ariaLabel={ariaLabel}
                ariaDescription={ariaDescription}
                disabled={disabled}
                iconName={iconName}
                id={toolbarButtonId}
                position={position}
                onClick={fileUploadRefLink}
                {...props}
            />
        </>
    );
};
```